# Java message when insert or replace in MYSQL database is empty

Tags: java, mysql

I use a parser to read data from a text file and writes them to the database. I wanted to find a way when the reading is made ​​empty more than 2 times and send an error message.

how can I do this?

This is possible?

I hope I have been explicit in doubt.

If someone can not understand ask me to clarify.

Thanks for the help.

The code of parser is that:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/RPR1BRG/Desktop/test.txt"));

String dados[] = new String[6];
String linha = reader.readLine();

while (linha != null) {

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(linha, ";\"");

    dados[0] = st.nextToken();
    dados[1] = st.nextToken(); 
    dados[2] = st.nextToken();
    dados[3] = st.nextToken();
    dados[4] = st.nextToken();
    dados[5] = st.nextToken();

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d-M-yy");

    PreparedStatement stmt = (PreparedStatement) conexao.prepareStatement("replace into registos" + " (date, hour, Id, Tem, Hum, pt) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    try {
        stmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(dateFormat.parse(dados[0]).getTime()));
        stmt.setString(2, dados[1]);
        stmt.setString(3, dados[2]);
        stmt.setString(4, dados[3]);
        stmt.setString(5, dados[4]);
        stmt.setString(6, dados[5]);

    } catch (java.text.ParseException ex) {
        Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
    }

    stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Can you explain: *when the reading is made ​​empty more than 2 times...*?

Comment: And, your code is reading the lines only once.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Ravinder. I place the reading file in 30 in 30 minutes. 
So in one hour he made ​​a 2 reading file. If these two readings the file is blank he warned. You undestand my answer? Thanks again

Comment: Do you mean that, if with an interval of 30 minutes each, if a file is read twice in an hour, and if these successive readings found an empty file, then a warning action has to be fired. Is that right?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what happens. I dont know is how to create warning :S

Comment: The function to read file is executed within a timer function...

Answer (score 0):

> *Do you mean that, if with an interval of 30 minutes each, if a file is
>   read twice in an hour, and if these successive readings found an empty
>   file, then a warning action has to be fired. Is that right? – 
>   Ravinder*
>
> *Yes that is exactly what happens. I dont know is how to create warning
>   The function to read file is executed within a timer function... – 
>   user3320956*

**Work around solution**:

In `Timer` implementation class, define

1. `lastReadTime` - to hold time when you last read the file.
2. `timeDiff` - to hold time difference from last read to current time.
3. If the gap is around 30 minutes, then set a warning message.
4. Define and call a method that `publishWarningMessage` that just arose. Publishing can be saving into a database or sending it over messaging SMS/EMAIL/... etc., depending on your requirement.
5. Continue or wait until next read.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I will try to work around your solution ;) I remembered now. is not there a way to, if no exists changes in the database for one hour raise an alert. But it's exactly what you said isnt it? Greetings